# Data annotation validation for integer value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a property called `ID_No` and would like validation on this: the length of this needs to be 13 digits, not more nor less

I have tried the following:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{13}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid ID Number")]
[Range(1000000000000, 9999999999999, ErrorMessage = "ID number cannot be longer than 13 digits")]
[Display(Name = "ID Number")]
public int ID_No { get; set; }
```

However it does not seem to work. It keeps saying the value "whatever 13 digits I enter" is invalid.

Any suggestions or help on how I can get this to work?

Comment: A `[RegularExpression]` attribute on a `int` makes no sense - the property would need to be typeof `string`. And the maximum value for an `int` is `2147483647` so an `int` cannot have 13 digits

Comment: What datatype you suggest? @StephenMuecke

Comment: You could use a `long` with a `[Range]` attribute (but definitely not a `[StringLength]` attribute) **or** a `string` with your `[RegularExpression]` and a `[StringLength]` attribute. It depends on what the value is actually for (are you doing numeric calculations with it? - it sound like its really some kind of identifier property?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is used on the registration page, The user just enters their ID number and I store it in the DB

Comment: Then a `string` is probably more appropriate (albeit you requirement for an `ID` for an `ID` to be exactly 13 characters is a bit odd)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is a South African ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180105/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID Number")]
    [Range(1000000000000, 9999999999999, ErrorMessage = "ID number cannot be longer than 13 digits")]
    [StringLength(13, MinimumLength=13, ErrorMessage = "ID number must be 13 char")]
    public long ID_No { get; set; }
```

Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g3ruR2

Comment: Seriously?? How could a 13 digit number be converted to an `int` - you just get an error in the POST method

Comment: use 'long` if you get error as int cannot hold that high value, check updated answer

Comment: Its not my question :) And what is the point of claiming to solve one issue and then create another

Comment: And if you are going to create fiddle, then show all the code to make it work - not omit the code that cause exceptions - [https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4MawN](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4MawN)

Comment: OP had issues with textbox length only

Comment: Wrong. The regex (the `{13}`) means it must be 13 characters. And your code throws an exception when the form is submitted.